# Multiple PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running into multiple compilation errors and unable to fix in spite of some of changes based on Stack Overflow suggestions on previous thread.
I am sorry, I am not familiar with PL/SQL, so I need help.

My initial code:

```
create or replace procedure exp_proc (
    v_job_name   in varchar2,
    v_dump_file  in varchar2,
    v_operation  in varchar2 default 'export',
    v_job_mode   in varchar2 default 'full',
    v_table      in varchar2(50) default NULL,
    v_parallel   in number default 1,
    v_directory  in varchar2 default 'datapump_dir',
    v_logfile    in varchar2 default 'logfile%u.log')
```

Error is:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/27     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:
         := . ) , @ % default character

6/43     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEFAULT" when expecting one of the following:
         . ( * % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..
         <an exponent (**)> || multiset
         The symbol "(" was inserted before "DEFAULT" to continue.

7/33     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of
```

Can someone help me review the code and help me fix

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing the (50) on line 6.